# Finding out if a substring is contained within another string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a storage array , where each volume is given a serial number. I am trying to match the serial number on the array to the serial numbers recorded by the operating system, for example :

eui.00d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae - this is the serial number (A) offered by the operating system
d118473ad54a40f200014bae - this is the serial number(B) offered by the storage device

Im trying to get python to figure out if A contains B , I have tried using *contains*, find and in - but they all return false or -1 - even though it can be seen that A contains B.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
serialnumber = "eui.00d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae"
volserial = "d118473ad54a40f200014bae"
found = volserial in serialnumber
print(found)

serialnumber = "eui.00d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae"
volserial = "d118473ad54a40f200014bae"
found = serialnumber.__contains__(volserial)
print(found)

serialnumber = "eui.00d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae"
volserial = "d118473ad54a40f200014bae"
found = serialnumber.find(volserial)
print(found)
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong ?" => well, to start with, asking for debugging help without providing all needed informations to diagnose the issue. Please edit your question with a __proper__ [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that - added in the fixes

Comment: ```in``` works fine. Your two serial numbers do not match each other. A is ```d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae``` and B is ```d118473ad54a40f200014bae```. If they do, then ```in``` should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
a = "abcde"
b = "bc"
c = b in a
print(c)
```

It works absolutely fine, You may have to check if the variables contain what you want them to

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though there is an incorrectly spelled storage device serial number:

```
serialnumber: eui.00d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae
volserial:          d118473ad54a40f200014bae
                                  ^
                                  missing 24a937
```

For the sake of getting you an answer... IF the storage device serial number is actually a substring AND if it always comes at the end of the os-generated string, then using the str method `.endwith()` will work:

Here is an example of this at work:

```
>>> serialnumber = 'eui.00d118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae' 
>>> volserial = 'd118473ad54a4024a937f200014bae' 
>>> serialnumber.endswith(volserial)
True
```

Similarly: IF the substring is present, then the `in` keyword will work:

```
>>> volserial in serialnumber                                                                                                                                                              
True
```

However, the purpose of the `.find()` method is to identify the location of the starting point for the substring. In this case, IF the substring is present, then the `.find()` method will tell you where the substring starts (in this case, at index 6):

```
>>> serialnumber.find(volserial)                                                                                                                                                           
6
```